# Edit Mode buttons for selecting vertices and edges vanished

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools

When I am in *Edit Mode* for my project, the *Mesh Select Mode* buttons have disappeared!

I loaded the default project and the buttons are where they are supposed to be; the issue is only in my project.

[image: Blender without selection tools]

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are in *Edit Mode* for a *Lattice Object*. *Lattice Objects* have one very specific type of *Edit Mode* and a user can only select vertices.

> A lattice consists of a three-dimensional non-renderable grid of vertices.

*Read more on the [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/rigging/lattice.html).*